# Pushing a lot of files in git

Tags: git

I have a very large git commit, with over 200,000 files. It took a long time to commit, but it is taking even longer to push.

The command I'm running is:

```
git push -v -u origin master
```

All I see is:

```
Counting objects: 251803, done.
```

And I wait. And wait. And wait.

Is it doing anything, or am I waiting in vain?

Comment: Does `top` show any activity? `iotop`?

Comment: Yes, its using 1 thread, about 1.2% CPU. 51 MB real memory. Seems kinda lazy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it's finding finding the delta's, which with over 200,000 files could be a lot.

If you are using only one thread, I believe git won't show that it's finding the delta's and it will take a while.

When you do a push of a smaller size, what is your output?
Do you see something like what's shown on the second line of the below output?

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
```

If you don't see the second line it means you are only using one thread.

Comment: Yes, I usually see output like this, with more than 1 thread.

Comment: I guess it just take a long time to resolve the delta's of 200,000+ files.

Comment: In the end I broke it up into smaller commits.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this sometimes when pushing over SSH.  Sometimes it helps to hit Ctrl-Z and then restart the process with `fg`, but sometimes I just have to wait.